# Is the sequence of sum of $\binom{n}{k}^{-1}$ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Is there a real number $M >0$ such that
$$S_n \leq M, \forall n \geq 1$$  where

$$  S_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}^{-1}, n\geq 1.$$

Thank you in advance

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you.

Comment: @A.MONNET The maximum seem to be for $n=3$ and $n=4$.